# Unexpected behavior of my site on change focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a Web Application with Knockout.js library and jQuery. Initially the form is like that:
[image: Init form]

Foreach input data, on change focus, the height of my table increase, like image below:
[image: After onchange focus]

Below the HTML code of my table:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col width="25%" />
        <col width="50%" />
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id="spnMaintenanceLastDate" class="Description">TEXT</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="dtpMaintenanceLastDate" class="DatePicker" data-bind="value: shopViewModel.lastMaintenanceDate" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="spnMaintenanceDescription" class="Description">TEXT</span>
            </td>   
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id="spnConcept" class="Description">TEXT</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="slcConcept" data-bind="value: shopViewModel.conceptId" style="width:100%"></select>
            </td>  
            <td rowspan="2">
                <textarea id="MaintenanceDescription" style="height:100%; width:100%; margin-right: 5px;" data-bind="value: shopViewModel.maintenanceDescription"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="Description">TEXT</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="slcFlooringType" data-bind="selectedOptions: shopViewModel.flooringTypes" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%"></select>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <hr class="hr" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Can you help me?
Thanks

Note: with Internet Explorer 8 I have not this problem, I have this problem with modern browser.

Comment: Can you provide a usable http://jsfiddle.net/ for our simulation?

Comment: Pls provide what you have along with the css markup.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to specifically set the vertical alignment of your `<td>` elements to something like `vertical-align:top` because this seems to be the behavior for the default which is `vertical-align:baseline`.

Try adding that css rule/style.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the height and vertical alignments. Like @mOchia said, `vertical-align` should be enough, but just to be safe, I recommend using a percentage and adding a `height` property.